# Debugging Android App on Device

Tags: android, debugging

I know there are many questions about this but none of them helped my situation.I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and I'm trying to debug an app on my LG phone. I followed this guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

I enabled USB debugging on my phone,set the project to debuggable in the manifest, and edited the /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules rules file. Here is the contents of the file:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

1004 is the vendor ID for LG.  The device is mounted; I can access it in my filesystem and the USB mounted indicator is in the notifications area. When I run adb devices, the phone is not listed, only the emulator is. It is also not recognized in Eclipse. How can I get Eclipse to recognize my device?

Comment: Yes. Is this another thing that doesn't work properly with the 64-bit version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is my ultimate script to adding rules for all Android devices. You should delete your  xx-android.rules files if you wrote it and make this with sudo:

```
#!/bin/bash

android_SDK=$1

if [[ $android_SDK == "" ]]
then
    echo 'usage: sudo add_device_rules_to_unix.sh /android-SDK/platform-tools/dir/path'
    exit
fi

PATH=$PATH:$android_SDK

rules_file="/etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules"

# Adding rules to 99-android.rules file
echo '# Acer
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666"
# Dell
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="413c", MODE="0666"
# Foxconn
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0489", MODE="0666"
# Garmin-Asus
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="091E", MODE="0666"
# Google
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"
# HTC
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
# Huawei
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666"
#Kyocera
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0482", MODE="0666"
# LG
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666"
# Motorola
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666"
# Nvidia
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0955", MODE="0666"
# Pantech
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="10A9", MODE="0666"
# Samsung
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
# Sharp
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04dd", MODE="0666"
# Sony Ericsson
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666"
# ZTE
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="19D2", MODE="0666"' > $rules_file

# Applying rules and restarting adb
chmod a+r $rules_file
service udev restart
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks. That's much better than hardcoding it in manually. I'll run this so hopefully I won't have to worry about it again.

Comment: If you are running a different version of Ubuntu (new/older) than this script you may have to change the number for `##-android.rules`. If you open up `/etc/udev/rules.d/` there should already be one or two rule files already there, just follow the naming convention already in that folder.

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem. The Android guide says to name the udev file 51-android.rules. But for newer version of Ubuntu (Karmic and sooner) it needs to be names 70-android.rules. This is the tutorial I followed: http://esausilva.com/2010/05/13/setting-up-adbusb-drivers-for-android-devices-in-linux-ubuntu/. Thanks for your answers though.

Answer (score 0):

You should install usb-drivers for your device (even if you have access with your file system). Maybe it's a standart driver, that allows you to use SD card on your phone (but nothing more).

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for generic adb drivers for LG for Ubuntu, install them, reboot and connect your phone. Then go to terminal, navigate to folder with adb and use the following command to see if your device is recognised:

```
./adb devices
```

If it shows your device, it is ready to be used with android sdk.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra step on 64 bit Ubuntu:
    apt-get install ia32-libs

Maybe this is the issue?

Comment: This was a problem before but I installed that library when I installed the SDK.