# HTC Desire usb connection issue with Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: connection, usb, ubuntu-10.04, android

I want to connect my HTC Desire with Ubuntu 10.04 for app debugging. But i am getting the following message upon running the command `adb devices`

```
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

I have tried the steps on the following link, but no success
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: try making files `70-android.rules` and `90-android.rules` and `99-android.rules` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check if you have a rule for HTC devices. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638635/debugging-android-app-on-device/8641534#8641534) is good script for this.

Then check if device allowed for debugging (on device: settings -> applications -> development ).

Comment: Thanks, phone is now detected. But i have to rename the rules file to 70-android.rules instead of 99-android.rules.