# Connecting HTC 3D to ADB

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, udev, linux-mint

I'm trying to connect my Android HTC3D phone to my laptop and have been chugging away at this problem for quite some time now. I have done some research and scanned stackoverflow but nothing has solved my problem. So far I have followed the tutorial at: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html but to no avail I would execute `./adb devices` and it would give me an empty list. I then started searching around and I found this stackoverflow Q&A [HTC Desire usb connection issue with Ubuntu 10.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860900/htc-desire-usb-connection-issue-with-ubuntu-10-04) which recommended I rename them to 70, 71, 90, and 99. So I tried that, still nothing... This lead me to another post: [Debugging Android App on Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638635/debugging-android-app-on-device/8641534#8641534) which gave me a script to automagically generate the 70-android.rules file... Still nothing.

So far **This is my setup**:

- OS - Linux Mint 11
- IDE - Eclipse
- Phone: HTC 3D
- Phone Model Number: PG86100
- Phone has been set to debugging mode via `Settings->Developer Options->USB Debugging`
- rules file:

  # Acer

  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666"

  # Dell

  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="413c", MODE="0666"

  # Foxconn

  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0489", MODE="0666"

  # Garmin-Asus

  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="091E", MODE="0666"

  # Google

  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"

  # HTC

  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"

  # Huawei

  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666"

  #Kyocera

  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0482", MODE="0666"

  # LG

  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666"

  # Motorola

  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666"

  # Nvidia

  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0955", MODE="0666"

  # Pantech

  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="10A9", MODE="0666"

  # Samsung

  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"

  # Sharp

  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04dd", MODE="0666"

  # Sony Ericsson

  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666"

  # ZTE

  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="19D2", MODE="0666"

Any help or advice would be amazing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SOLUTION:

I was using a griffon USB cable I had picked up at BestBuy for my old cellphone. Switched that cable out with the USB cable the HTC came with an badabang-badaboom it worked.

Comment: I've had the same problem.  Sometimes usb cable is for charging only and not data as well.

Comment: I never knew that, I thought USB was USB but apparently I was mistaken. Paradigm shift....